# acts-as-taggable-on fails in finding items belonging to tags which contains spaces and non English characters such as åäö

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm using the following code to retrieve all products tagged with a specific tag.

```
tag = The tag for the products which you would like to find

Product.tagged_with(tag, :on => "product_tags").each do |product|
  # CODE
end
```

This works for most tagged items. But I'm not able to retrieve products which are tagged with a tag containing the Swedish characters åäö and spaces.

Act as taggable will find products tagged with "a b c", but it will fail finding products tagged with "å ä ö".

It works fine to tagging a product with "å ä ö". The tag will show up when requesting all tags for a product tagged with "å ä ö". The only problem is finding all products tagged with "å ä ö".

What should I do to get acts-as-taggable to work properly with åäö? Could this be an encoding problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show us the DB queries when you execute

```
Product.tagged_with(tag, :on => "product_tags")
```

It will help you to find if it's a acts_as_taggable problem or your database column encodings.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The problem had nothing to do with encoding. The SQL query created looked like this.   ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" WHERE (name LIKE 'ö' OR name LIKE 'ä' OR name LIKE 'å'). Acts-as-taggable was making an OR query since the delimiter was set to space. See https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/wiki for how to change delimiter.